# How to verify user entered password matches hashed password stored in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

What is the basic code that takes a user entered password and checks if it matches the hashed password stored in a MySQL database table?

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic non-secure example of how to verify that the user entered password matches the password_hash version stored in the database. I contribute this Q&A because I was unable to find a basic understandable answer online.

To test this, you need a database connection, a database table named `user` with data (of course), and an error page (here error.html.php).

I hope it is helpful.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'submit')
{
    include 'your database connection file';

    try 
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT password FROM user
            WHERE email = :email';
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);
        $s->execute();
    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
        $error = 'Error fetching password.' . $e->getMessage();
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }

    // Assign single row result to $result as associative array
    $result = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Check for match using boolean password_verify() 
    if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $result['password']))
    {
        echo '<p style="color:#0000ff">Match!</p>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<p style="color:#ff0000">Sorry, wrong password.</p>';
    }   
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Password Verify</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder=" Email">
            <input type="text" name="password" placeholder=" Password">
            <button type="submit" name="action" value="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>  
</html>
```